# Django-admin is is not recognized

Tags: python, django, cmd

I've been trying to start a Django project and when I try to create a new project, it gives me an error

```
django-admin startproject example
```

> The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program.

I've added Python to environmental variable and of course installed Django package and tried all the other options on googling, nothing worked. Is there something I'm missing? Im on Win 10

Solved it after uninstalling Python + django separately, then reinstalling.

Comment: What is the output of `python -V` as well as `pip show Django` from cmd? Also, have you already tried to steps found here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/faq/troubleshooting/

Comment: @JDH pytho -V gives ' The term 'python' is not recognized'
pip show django works showing the version, author, license etc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to run it on windows 10 CMD. It worked well on anaconda3powershell using `django-admin startproject project`.

To create a project using windows CMD or any other terminal that does not support django-admin use the following.`python -m django startproject Project`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you need to uninstall python and when you download it again you need to check the "add python to path" or something similar (like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14OSE.png))

Comment: Worked for me, just installed python and django on Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

First check the django version with:

python -m django --version

If it's installed and you have a recent version, I suggest uninstalling and installing again, there might have been some mistakes with some package. It's weird...

Comment: It says Python is not recognized. I've done the uninstall and install thing removing pycharm, Anaconda and all its contents as well

Answer (score 0):

First, open your command prompt in windows then type your python directory(path).
Then type:

```
<your-python-path> -m venv venv 
<your-python-path> venv\Scripts\activate
(venv) <your-python-path> pip install django
```

Let it install the django and then start your project

```
(venv) <your-python-path> django-admin startproject PROJECT_NAME
```

If you couldn't make it watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXPNB3hGUVs&list=LL&index=4&t=433s